# PHP- How to do str_shuffle make different value?

Tags: php, random

PHP- How to do str_shuffle make different values??

```
    $randomcode="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
$randomcode='NT'.substr(str_shuffle($str),5,8);
    echo $randomcode.'<br>';
    echo $randomcode.'<br>';
```

result:

```
NT2ZCI1qdX
NT2ZCI1qdX
```

How to make different values??
I want to insert it into my database.

```
$randomcode="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
$randomcode=substr(str_shuffle($str),5,8);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into AGEGroup (AGE,hidecode) values (:age,$randomcode)");

foreach ($_POST['age'] as $age) {
    $stmt->execute([':age'=>$age]);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You have to do `str_shuffle()` every time you want to make a new value. In your code, you only do it once, and assign that value to a variable. That variable won't change unless you change it.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want to use that. What is it for exactly? Maybe there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, I exact it auto-insert the random code to database

Comment: @superMay_2 This method does not create unique strings, you can **and will** get duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate your code inside the loop.

```
//list of possible characters in generated code
$charmap = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

//note using `:randomcode` instead of the direct variable
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into AGEGroup (AGE) values (:age, :randomcode)");

foreach ($_POST['age'] as $age) {
    
    //create a "random" string that is 8 characters.
    //string will never repeat any characters, and can create duplicates
    $code = 'NT' . substr(str_shuffle($charmap), -8);

    //send variables to query on each loop
    $stmt->execute([':age' => $age, ':randomcode' => $code]);
}
```

As I said in the comments in the code, this method probably has the tendency to create duplicate codes. It will also not contain any duplicate letters/numbers.